# I want to replace the text inside span of parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the text inside span. But span doesn't have a class and parent div doesn't have an id. I can't change the html it is not in my hand. So how can I change text of span with js?

```
<div class="mobilMenuAcButton">
<span>MENU</span>
<i class="fal fa-bars"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: You can also get elements via [classname or any other valid CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```js
let div = document.querySelector(".mobilMenuAcButton");
let span = div.querySelector("span");
span.innerHTML = "NEW MENU";
```

```html
<div class="mobilMenuAcButton">
  <span>MENU</span>
  <i class="fal fa-bars"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI: you can combine the selectors instead of querying twice like: `let span = document.querySelector('.mobilMenuAcButton span')` or just call [firstElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/firstElementChild).

Comment: @Reyno considering that OP is a beginner, this is done deliberately so its easier to understand.

Comment: @AhsanKhan and Reyno thanks alot both! Codes are worked perfect and I changed the text. One more question can I add another class of a div to same code? Like this;

`code`
let span = document.querySelector('.mobilMenuAcButton span')
let span = document.querySelector('.mobilMenuBT span')
span.innerHTML = "MENÜ";

Comment: @Muraterdoğan if you need to change multiple elements you can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) where you can provide a comma separated list. I've created an answer to demonstrate this

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for setting the text:

`node.textContent = yourText`

and this to return the value:

`node.textContent`

Answer (score 0):

[MDN Referance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#a_more_complex_selector)

```js
let span = document.querySelector(".mobilMenuAcButton span");
span.textContent = "test";
```

```html
<div class="mobilMenuAcButton">
<span>MENU</span>
<i class="fal fa-bars"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example by using jQuery.

```js
//This can update the content of sample span
$(".mobilMenuAcButton span").html('New Menu');

//If you have multiple span in different level
//better use '>' or first() to specific select the target
//'>' standard for first level of children inside parent
//Both line below can do the works
$(".mobilMenuAcButton > span").html('New Menu');
$(".mobilMenuAcButton span").first().html('New Menu');
```

```html
<!-- Insert the following line to head tag to use jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="mobilMenuAcButton">
  <span>MENU</span>
  <i class="fal fa-bars"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change multiple elements you can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Afterwards just loop over each element and change its content.

```js
const menuSpans = document.querySelectorAll('.mobilMenuAcButton span, .mobilMenuBT span');

for(const span of menuSpans) {
  span.textContent = 'MENÜ';
}
```

```html
<div class="mobilMenuAcButton">
  <span>MENU</span>
  <i class="fal fa-bars"></i>
</div>

<div class="mobilMenuBT">
  <span>MENU</span>
  <i class="fal fa-bars"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: awesome that works perfect thanks alot for your help!

And thanks to others for their help!